# Regex to get instagram picture (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to check if a URL is an Instagram picture and return just the beginning part of the URL with the /p/PICTUREID

So far this is what I've been able to come up with:

```
^(.*instagram.com\/p\/.*)\/
```

This however requires there to be a trailing slash but I do not want to require it.

Examples (that should match):

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY/?post->
https://www.instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY

http://www.instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY/ ->
http://www.instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY

instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY ->
instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY
```

How do I stop at the trailing slash if it exists and anything else after?

Here is my regex101 for testing:

https://regex101.com/r/JJS2kz/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can use this regex here to match all the examples you provided:

```
/(https?:\/\/www\.)?instagram\.com(\/p\/\w+\/?)/
```

### Explanation

The first part of the regex looks for `http` or `https`followed by a `www.` and makes the whole combination optional.

```
(https?:\/\/www\.)?
```

The second part is looking for the string `instagram.com`

```
instagram\.com
```

And the third part is looking for whatever letters followed by the slash after the `/p/`, with an optional trailing slash `/`. Note that this part of the regex is in parenthesis so you can retrieve it later when you use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
(\/p\/\w+\/?)
```

### Solution 2

If you want to be able to support the following pattern as well (**with** the `http/https` and **without** the `www`):

```
http://instagram.com/p/BkbwlrfjGHY
http://instagram.com/p/BkbwlrfjGHY/
https://instagram.com/p/BkbwlrfjGHY
https://instagram.com/p/BkbwlrfjGHY
```

You could use this regex:

```
/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?)?instagram\.com(\/p\/\w+\/?)/
```

### Example

```
$string = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/abcd/?post->
           https://www.instagram.com/p/efgh

           http://www.instagram.com/p/iJkL/ ->
           http://www.instagram.com/p/MnNadfoadf

           instagram.com/p/ACDOFfaf ->
           instagram.com/p/AFMDAOF';

preg_match_all('/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?)?instagram\.com(\/p\/\w+\/?)/', $string, $matches);
```

Then if you do a `var_dump` of `$matches`:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(33) "https://www.instagram.com/p/abcd/"
    [1]=>
    string(32) "https://www.instagram.com/p/efgh"
    [2]=>
    string(32) "http://www.instagram.com/p/iJkL/"
    [3]=>
    string(37) "http://www.instagram.com/p/MnNadfoadf"
    [4]=>
    string(24) "instagram.com/p/ACDOFfaf"
    [5]=>
    string(23) "instagram.com/p/AFMDAOF"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "https://www."
    [1]=>
    string(12) "https://www."
    [2]=>
    string(11) "http://www."
    [3]=>
    string(11) "http://www."
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "www."
    [1]=>
    string(4) "www."
    [2]=>
    string(4) "www."
    [3]=>
    string(4) "www."
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [5]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [3]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "/p/abcd/"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "/p/efgh"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "/p/iJkL/"
    [3]=>
    string(13) "/p/MnNadfoadf"
    [4]=>
    string(11) "/p/ACDOFfaf"
    [5]=>
    string(10) "/p/AFMDAOF"
  }
}
```

And now to retrieve each ids, you can use the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach($matches[3] as $instagramId){
    echo $instagramId . "<br>";
}
```

And the result will be:

```
/p/abcd/
/p/efgh
/p/iJkL/
/p/MnNadfoadf
/p/ACDOFfaf
/p/AFMDAOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the regexp that works also for case when username is in the path

`^((https?):\/\/)?(www.)?instagram\.com(\/[A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?\/p\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/?`

Test case:

`https://instagram.com/p/BryAm8hnjGk`

`https://www.instagram.com/anettletigre/p/BryAm8hnjGk/`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above written information and adding a bit from myself, I present a universal way to get the CODE:

```
(?:(?:(?:(?:https?)(?::\/\/))?(?:www\.))?)instagram\.com\/?(?<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{1,30})?\/p\/(?<code>[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)\/?
```

Example:

```
$string = '
    instagram.com/p/code1
    instagram.com/username1/p/code2
    instagram.com/p/code3/
    instagram.com/username2/p/code4/

    http://instagram.com/p/code5
    http://instagram.com/username3/p/code6
    http://instagram.com/p/code7/
    http://instagram.com/username4/p/code8/
    https://instagram.com/p/code9
    https://instagram.com/username5/p/code10
    https://instagram.com/p/code11/
    https://instagram.com/username6/p/code12/

    http://www.instagram.com/p/code13
    http://www.instagram.com/username7/p/code14
    http://www.instagram.com/p/code15/
    http://www.instagram.com/username8/p/code16/

    https://www.instagram.com/p/code17
    https://www.instagram.com/username9/p/code18
    https://www.instagram.com/p/code19/
    https://www.instagram.com/username10/p/code20/


    instagram.com/username11/p/code21?utm_source=...
    instagram.com/username12/p/code22/?utm_source=...
    https://www.instagram.com/p/code23?utm_source=...
    https://www.instagram.com/username13/p/code24/?utm_source=...';

preg_match_all("/(?:(?:(?:(?:https?)(?::\/\/))?(?:www\.))?)instagram\.com\/?(?<username>[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{1,30})?\/p\/(?<code>[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)\/?/", $string, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
```

Answer:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => instagram.com/p/code1
            [1] => instagram.com/username1/p/code2
            [2] => instagram.com/p/code3/
            [3] => instagram.com/username2/p/code4/
            [4] => instagram.com/p/code5
            [5] => instagram.com/username3/p/code6
            [6] => instagram.com/p/code7/
            [7] => instagram.com/username4/p/code8/
            [8] => instagram.com/p/code9
            [9] => instagram.com/username5/p/code10
            [10] => instagram.com/p/code11/
            [11] => instagram.com/username6/p/code12/
            [12] => http://www.instagram.com/p/code13
            [13] => http://www.instagram.com/username7/p/code14
            [14] => http://www.instagram.com/p/code15/
            [15] => http://www.instagram.com/username8/p/code16/
            [16] => https://www.instagram.com/p/code17
            [17] => https://www.instagram.com/username9/p/code18
            [18] => https://www.instagram.com/p/code19/
            [19] => https://www.instagram.com/username10/p/code20/
            [20] => instagram.com/username11/p/code21
            [21] => instagram.com/username12/p/code22/
            [22] => https://www.instagram.com/p/code23
            [23] => https://www.instagram.com/username13/p/code24/
        )

    [username] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => username1
            [2] => 
            [3] => username2
            [4] => 
            [5] => username3
            [6] => 
            [7] => username4
            [8] => 
            [9] => username5
            [10] => 
            [11] => username6
            [12] => 
            [13] => username7
            [14] => 
            [15] => username8
            [16] => 
            [17] => username9
            [18] => 
            [19] => username10
            [20] => username11
            [21] => username12
            [22] => 
            [23] => username13
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => username1
            [2] => 
            [3] => username2
            [4] => 
            [5] => username3
            [6] => 
            [7] => username4
            [8] => 
            [9] => username5
            [10] => 
            [11] => username6
            [12] => 
            [13] => username7
            [14] => 
            [15] => username8
            [16] => 
            [17] => username9
            [18] => 
            [19] => username10
            [20] => username11
            [21] => username12
            [22] => 
            [23] => username13
        )

    [code] => Array
        (
            [0] => code1
            [1] => code2
            [2] => code3
            [3] => code4
            [4] => code5
            [5] => code6
            [6] => code7
            [7] => code8
            [8] => code9
            [9] => code10
            [10] => code11
            [11] => code12
            [12] => code13
            [13] => code14
            [14] => code15
            [15] => code16
            [16] => code17
            [17] => code18
            [18] => code19
            [19] => code20
            [20] => code21
            [21] => code22
            [22] => code23
            [23] => code24
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => code1
            [1] => code2
            [2] => code3
            [3] => code4
            [4] => code5
            [5] => code6
            [6] => code7
            [7] => code8
            [8] => code9
            [9] => code10
            [10] => code11
            [11] => code12
            [12] => code13
            [13] => code14
            [14] => code15
            [15] => code16
            [16] => code17
            [17] => code18
            [18] => code19
            [19] => code20
            [20] => code21
            [21] => code22
            [22] => code23
            [23] => code24
        )

)
```

Comment: @Second2None , Passing the link to the post to instagram in any format - the regular expression returns the desired part, namely the CODE. Also, if there is a uername in the link, it also returns

Comment: Not to me buddy, in your post :)

Answer (score 0):

If **instagram.com** is the only URL you're searching for, **strpos** will run faster than a regex:

```
<?php

$test = [
'https://www.instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY/',
'https://www.instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY',
'http://www.instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY/',
'http://www.instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY',
'instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY/',
'someother.com/p/asdfads',
'instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY'];

$target = 'instagram.com';
$offset = strlen($target);
foreach ($test as $url) {
        $p = strpos($url, $target);
        if ($p === false) {
                echo 'Not an instagram URL'.PHP_EOL;
        } else {
                $instagramId = rtrim(substr($url,$p+$offset),'/');

                echo $instagramId.' is an instagram id'.PHP_EOL;
        }
}
```

Comment: I want to extract the picture ID as well as checking to see if its an Instagram URL so regex I believe is the way to go.

Comment: @JoeJankowiak - updated to assign the instagram id to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
(https?:\/\/www\.)?(?:instagram.com|instagr.am)\/p\/([^\/]*)\/?
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not really an answer to the OP, but I wanted to mention, that I often use a different way to check URLs, `parse_url`. It is very verbose, but I find it pretty clear to read and understand. Made a quick demo for Instagram:

```php
<?php

$parts = parse_url('https://www.instagram.com/p/BKbwlrfjGHY/?post');

if(in_array($parts['host'], ['instagram.com', 'www.instagram.com'])) {
    // is instagram url
    $path = explode('/', trim($parts['path'], '/'));

    if(count($path) > 1) {
        if(mb_strtolower($path[0]) == 'p') {
            $post_id = $path[1];
        }
    }
}

$result = $parts['host'].'/p/'.$post_id;
```

It is pretty trivial to add protocol to the URL or to do some more sanity checking, if required, or even bundle it into a function. Hope it helps, as an alternative solution to the problem.